# "meagre ambition"

Tags: meaning-in-context

What does this sentence mean? Specifically, what does "meagre" mean here? As per dictionaries, it should mean "inadequate", but the character does display self-denial. The usage of the word "ambition" seems out of place too. Wells's short story The Purple Pileus

> And Coombes was such a harmless little man, too, nourished mentally on Self-Help, and with a **meagre** ambition of self-denial and competition that was to end in a "sufficiency."

Comment: Source please ?

Comment: "Meagre" doesn't mean "inadequate". It means weak, poor quality, low amount, but not for the purpose of any particular goal.

Comment: H.G. Wells:  https://en.wikisource.org/wiki/The_Plattner_Story_and_Others/The_Purple_Pileus

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An *ambition of self-denial and competition* is a somewhat positive description. Combining that with *meagre* makes it align with the general evaluation *harmless little man*, what Coombes was before his psychedelic experience with the magic mushrooms.
Whether *meagre* is taken as insufficient or small and weak doesn't change the sense of the passage.

Comment: If you replace "meagre" with "insufficient", both are supposed to mean the same thing, it gets confusing